# C# xdocument create xml file

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I need to create a xml using Xdocument ,I need to loop throught he datatable and adding the employee data.  below is how the document will be created when it is hard coded , how can I modify my code to loop through and employee object and  populate the data in XML.

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(

            new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-16", null),

            new XElement(empNM + "Employees",

                new XElement("Employee",

                    new XElement("EmpId", "5"),

                    new XElement("Name", "Kimmy"),

                    new XElement("Sex", "Female")

                    )));
```

Comment: You mean a list/array of employee objects?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to replace  `new XElement("Employee")` part with a `Select`:

```
employeeList.Select(e => new XElement("Employee", new XElement("EmpId", e.EmpId)...)
```

If you don't have a generic list and only have `DataTable` you can use [`AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) method before `Select`.